# Regex \A until \r syntax

Tags: regex, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

How could I write "Get everything from beginning of string (\A) until carriage return character (\r)" and leave rest as is in regex? I would like to use this in InDesign's GREP feature to style the first paragraph of a text box (before a carriage return).

Comment: This question belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Ok sorry I'm new to stack communities

Comment: And just why would it belong there?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions related to code. Superuser is for general computing questions. It's an easy thing to mix up and sometimes the lines blur a little bit. InDesign javascripting questions, for example, could go on either site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search from the beginning of an string to a defined character:

Here the defined character is: \r and it is not included in the match.
Replace \r with the character you want.

```
\A[^\r]+
```

---

Here the defined character is: \r and it is included in the match.
Replace both \r with the character you want.

```
\A[^\r]+\r
```

---

To understand the regexes:

- `\A` Assert the position at the beginning of the string.
- `[^\r]+` Match every character that is not a carriage return character between one and unlimited times.
- `\r` Match the carriage return character.